# jQuery: mouseout not working. Sliding panel

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create .mouseover and .mouseleave function in jQuery to made facebook like box, and get stuck with it. 
(can't use toggle because i have div with fb plugin, and div with fb icon which works as trigger. both in slider div)

This is working:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).animate({ left: "+250px"
            });
        });
    });
```

while this is not:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).animate({ left: "+250px"
            }).mouseout(function (){
            $(this).animate({ left: "-250px" });
        });
    });
```

was looking so long, and doesn't see nothing wrong with this. (Searched many jQuery topics on stackoverflow too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First... you need to `.stop` the previous animation... and second... use `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slider').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ left: "+250px"});
        }).mouseleave(function (){
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({ left: "-250px" });
        });
    });
```

And in your code, there seems to be a problem with unclosing brackets...

Comment: Uff. It helped, thanks ;) I thought that '})' before mouseleave is closing tag to animate before this. If you use stop, you don't need to use -250px then?

Comment: Still need to use -250px ... because it will run this event before stopping... so when it should move -250px, it will...